# Reactjs variable is returning with undefined after useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am very new to Reactjs, I am working on retrieving some data in order to display it, everything gets displayed however, when I filter there is an error that comes up "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined", after debugging I found out that dataList is returning with undefined when typing anything in the search bar.
Appreciate your assistance.

```
function App() {

  var dataList;

useEffect(() => {
// http get request
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': '***********************',
  'UserAddressId': ****,
  'StoreId': *
}

axios.get('https://app.markitworld.com/api/v2/user/products', {
  headers: headers
})
  .then((response) => {
    dataList = response.data.data.products
    setData(dataList)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}, []);

const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState(dataList);

// exclude column list from filter
const excludeColumns = ["id"];

// handle change event of search input
const handleChange = value => {
setSearchText(value);
filterData(value);
};

// filter records by search text
const filterData = (value) => {
console.log("dataList", dataList)
const lowercasedValue = value.toLowerCase().trim();
if (lowercasedValue === "") setData(dataList);
else {
  const filteredData = dataList.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
      excludeColumns.includes(key) ? false : 
      item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedValue)
    );
  });
  setData(filteredData);
}
}

return (
<div className="App">
  Search: <input
    style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
    type="text"
    placeholder="Type to search..."
    value={searchText}
    onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
  />
  <div className="box-container">
    {data && data.length > 0 ? data.map((d, i) => {
      return <div key={i} className="box">
        <b>Title: </b>{d.title}<br />
        <b>Brand Name: </b>{d.brand_name}<br />
        <b>Price: </b>{d.price}<br />
        <b>Status: </b>{d.status}<br />
      </div>
    }) : "Loading..."}
    <div className="clearboth"></div>
    {data && data.length === 0 && <span>No records found to display!</span>}
  </div>
  </div>
  );
  }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up a stateful `data` variable with a separate non-stateful, local `dataList` variable. The `dataList` only gets assigned to inside the `axios.get`, so it's not defined on subsequent renders; the `setData(dataList)` puts it into the stateful `data`, but the `dataList` on subsequent renders remains undefined.

To make things easier to understand, remove the `dataList` variable entirely, and just use the stateful `data`.

You also probably don't want to discard the existing data when the user types something in - instead, figure out what items should be displayed *while rendering*; rework the `filterData` so that its logic is only carried out while returning the JSX.

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    // http get request
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': '***********************',
        'UserAddressId': ****,
        'StoreId': *
    }

    axios.get('https://app.markitworld.com/api/v2/user/products', {
        headers: headers
    })
        .then((response) => {
            setData(response.data.data.products);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}, []);

// handle change event of search input
const handleChange = value => {
    setSearchText(value);
};

// filter records by search text
const filterData = () => {
    const lowercasedValue = searchText.toLowerCase().trim();
    return lowercasedValue === ""
        ? data
        : data.filter(
            item => Object.keys(item).some(
                key => excludeColumns.includes(key) ? false :
                    item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedValue)
            )
        );
}
```

And change

```
{data && data.length > 0 ? data.map((d, i) => {
```

to

```
{filterData().map((d, i) => {
```

Your `searchText` should also be *text*, not an array: this

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState([]);
```

should be

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
```

Comment: I've made these changes but it is coming up with an error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Your `searchText` should be text, not an array, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, but for some reason still not working, I mean it is loading the data and everything but when I type anything in the search bar it comes up with TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Comment: If the value might be null, how about using `String` instead of calling `toString` on the value? `String(item[key])` or maybe just filter out null/undefined values first - whichever suits your purposes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to maintain an additional non-state variable `dataList` as the local state `data` would serve the purpose.

#### API Call Code:

You should directly store the response from API after null checks satisfy.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const headers = {
    // key value pairs go here
  };

  // http request
  axios.get(endPoint, {
    headers,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // set data directly null checks
      setData(response.data.data.products);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

#### Filteration Code

Use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook which would return a memoized version of the callback, unless the value of `data` changes.

```
const filterData = useCallback((value) => {
  console.log('data', data);
  // rest of code
}, [data]);
```